# PyCharm not finding Anaconda Python, giving “can't open file 'python.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory?”

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, anaconda

I am new to Python. Installed Anaconda on my system. I installed PyCharm too. When I try to run a file from PyCharm I get this error message:

```
C:/Users/liuzh/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/Scripts/python.exe
C:/Users/liuzh/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/python.py
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/liuzh/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/python.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Process finished with exit code 2

Comment: Could you give more information on which file you are trying to run and how?

Comment: Since you are installing Anaconda, you can try the Spyder IDE first (which comes packaged with Anaconda) and check whether all your installations are working properly. Then you can migrate to a new IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: From the stackstrace it is as if you are trying to run a file you named `python.py` in the scratches folder which was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As it says that there is no such file or directory. You can try two things:

1. install pip, install python and change your base directory interpreter of your pycharm project to that python.
2. if you have properly installed anaconda, you can use anaconda navigator to install pycharm. Which will chances are do everything for you, so you don't have to worry about file path or anything.